# Is this rank-$1$ matrix semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite, rank-1-matrices

I have a matrix, $X = xx^T$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Is the matrix $X$ semidefinite?

Comment: What is $y^T X y$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any vector $y$ one has $y^T X y=y^Txx^Ty = (y^Tx)^2$ (since $y^Tx=x^Ty$ is a scalar), so the answer is yes.