# Is this rank-$1$ (complex) matrix positive semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite, hermitian-matrices, rank-1-matrices

In [Is this rank-$1$ matrix semidefinite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/801960), I have seen that $X = xx^T$ is PSD when $x$ is real. What about the case when $X$ is Hermitian?

I know that it is PSD but I'm not exactly sure how to prove it. One final question is about the rank of $X$ if $x$ is a vector, it should be one. Is that right?

Comment: This is also true with complex numbers. In that case, the matrix $X=xx^*$, where $*$ denotes the complex conjugate transpose, satisfies $X=X^*$ (Hermitian matrix) and is positive semidefinite with a unique positive eigenvalue equal to $x^*x$.

Comment: I have proved its PSD using the principal minors and the rank, however, I'm not sure how to prove it using the $v^*Xv$

Comment: If you are familiar with optimization, you can try to find the minimum of $v^*Xv$ such that $v^*v=1$. Otherwise, you can find its eigendecomposition.

Comment: @eng If $X=xx^*$, show that $v^*Xv=|x^*v|^2$

Comment: I was trying on my own with a 2x2 matrices. I got:
$$x_1^2v_1^2+x_1^*v_1v_2^*x_2+x_1v_1^*v_2x_2^*+x_2^2v_2^2$$
I know that this is positive but is it equivalent to your answer?

Comment: @eng How do you know that this is positive?

Comment: @BenGrossmann My understanding is that $x_1^2v_1^2+x_1^*v_1v_2^*x_2$ is the conjugate of $x_1v_1^*v_2x_2^*+x_2^2v_2^2$. Adding $a+bi$ and $a-bi$ results in $2a$ but you are correct, I don't know how to guarantee that $2a$ is non-negative. I would appreciate your feedback in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already computed, with $X = xx^*$, we have
$$
v^*Av = |x_1v_1|^2 + \bar x_1 v_1 x_2 \bar v_2 + x_1 \bar v_1 \bar x_2 v_2 + |x_2v_2|^2.
$$
Verify that this is the same as
$$
|x^*v|^2 = x^*v \overline{x^*v} = (x_1v_1 + x_2v_2)(\overline{x_1 v_1 + x_2 v_2}).
$$
Alternatively, simply note that
$$
v^*Xv = v^*xx^*v = (v^*x)(v^*x)^* = |v^*x|^2.
$$
In either case, we note that $v^*Xv$ is the magnitude of a complex number and is therefore non-negative.

Comment: I appreciate that! Thanks